# Fabricjs: fill svg with image pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, coffeescript, fabricjs

I’d like to load my SVG file, and fill it with pattern, created from my image file.

Here is my current approach:

```
canvas = new fabric.Canvas('mainCanvas')
# image = new fabric.Image(img[0])
# console.log image
fabric.loadSVGFromURL '/assets/my.svg',
  (objects) ->
    fabric.util.loadImage "url/to/my/image", (image) ->
      console.log image
      svg = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects)
      svg = svg.scale(0.04).set(fill: "black", opacity: 0.5 )
      svg.fill = new fabric.Pattern
        source: image
        repeat: "no-repeat"
      canvas.add(svg)
      canvas.renderAll()
```

Originally, I tried to use fabric.Image instance (img is jQuery image element, so I’m passing raw htmlelement to constructor), but just to be sure & use code more similar to [pattern tutorial](http://fabricjs.com/patterns/) I’m using loadImage method.

Unfortunately, this code seems to not work (svg is loaded, but there’s no pattern on it). Is it possible to fill svg with pattern? If so, how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is likely that your SVG shape is parsed as a `fabric.PathGroup` rather than `fabric.Path`. Since `fabric.PathGroup` consists of multiple `fabric.Path` objects, you need to set their fill value rather than fill value of PathGroup instance itself.

```
if (obj instanceof fabric.PathGroup) {
  obj.getObjects().forEach(function(o) { o.fill = pattern; });
}
else {
  obj.fill = pattern;
}
```

If you go to [kitchensink](http://fabricjs.com/kitchensink/) and use "Patternify" button, you can see that it works with more complex shapes (this is exactly the code we're using there):

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment, unfortunately, that’s not the case. Here’s my current code: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=HUeBkq1t – which still does not work. Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: Looks like you're assigning image, not pattern, to "fill" property.

Comment: Sorry that I didn’t respond earlier, however you’re dead right! I was looking like milion times on that code, inspecting what’s wrong, and I didn’t found that error. Thank you very much!