# fabric.js fill a SVG or a PNG with a PNG pattern

Tags: javascript, canvas, design-patterns, fabricjs

I'm currently trying to use the [fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/articles/) library to fill a PNG or a SVG with a pattern. I tried to get some inspiration from [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18588036/fabricjs-fill-svg-with-image-pattern/18616032#18616032), but couldn't make it work as it is explained.

Here is my pattern:

[image]

Here is my PNG template (can't upload SVG, but it's [here](https://files.fm/u/d3ysfuy8). And the SVG is white):

[image]

```
// GET AND INIT CANVAS (400x400)
canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');

// MY PATHS
let patternURL = "../images/background1.jpg";
let SVGURL = "../svg/test.svg";

// CREATE MY SVG ELEMENT
fabric.loadSVGFromURL(SVGURL, function(objects, options) {
    // CREATE MY PATTERN IMAGE
    fabric.Image.fromURL(patternURL, function(patternImage) {
        svg = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
        svg = svg.set({"opacity": 1});
        svg.getObjects().forEach(function(e) {
            // IF I DON'T USE THIS LINE, THE SVG REMAIN WHITE
            e.fill = patternImage
        });

        canvas.add(svg);
    });
});
```

Here is what I have after the execution of my code:

[image]

NB: I can move the PNG, and if I add `canvas.add(patternImage);` before adding the SVG, I get this result:

[image]

(so the pattern is loaded as it should).

I think I'm getting pretty close, must be missing the `KEY` line in the code. Do you have any helpful information or could redirect me into the right place?

EDIT: Here is the (sort of, I just did it on paint) background I wish to obtain :

[image]

Comment: you want that as a background or overlay?

Comment: I just added in comment at the end the kind of thing I wish to obtain.

Comment: You have that two images?

Comment: I have a lot of patterns, like the square one (first picture), and a lot of templates (like the second one in SVG or in PNG). I need a function that take those 2, and create a 3rd one dynamically (like the last one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create another canvas for your pattern. And use that in fabric.Pattern and then use that pattern object to fill.

```
fabric.loadSVGFromURL(SVGURL, function(objects, options) {
  fabric.Image.fromURL(patternURL, function(patternImage) {
    svg = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
    var patternSourceCanvas = new fabric.StaticCanvas();
    patternSourceCanvas.add(patternImage);
    patternSourceCanvas.setDimensions({
      width: patternImage.getScaledWidth(),
      height: patternImage.getScaledHeight()
    });
    patternSourceCanvas.renderAll();
    var pattern = new fabric.Pattern({
        source: patternSourceCanvas.getElement()
      },
      function(patternObj) {
        svg.getObjects().forEach(function(e) {
          e.fill = patternObj
        });
        canvas.add(svg);
      });
  })
})
```

Comment: Damn that is working ! I was becoming crazy about this issue but there is very few people asking for achieving that. Just one more question: is it doable with a PNG instead of a SVG ? Thank you very much !

Comment: @tonito, nope we can't fill an image.